# How to change vue default project info template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to vue.js and vuetify.js. When I use command

```
vue init webpack app
```

the vue will give some default project setting such as project name, author,..
The question is, Where are the default setting from？How can I change to my customised default setting to make further projects being created faster?

Comment: If Vue is asking you for a library to install along your installation process, like: vuex, vue-router, testing .... then those are added to your package.json to be downloade along the install thus, are not stored somewhere for you to "activate" or not. If you are talking about the other things like linting and other configration options, those you can usually dig inside the webpack configuration file and modify/add them from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own template via:

```
vue init username/repo my-project-name
```

Details [from the official repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/master#custom-templates):

> #### Custom Templates
>
> It's unlikely to make everyone happy with the official templates. You
>   can simply fork an official template and then use it via `vue-cli`
>   with:
>
> ```
> vue init username/repo my-project
> ```
>
> Where `username/repo` is the GitHub repo shorthand for your fork.
>
> The shorthand repo notation is passed to
>   [download-git-repo](https://github.com/flipxfx/download-git-repo) so
>   you can also use things like `bitbucket:username/repo` for a Bitbucket
>   repo and `username/repo#branch` for tags or branches.
>
> If you would like to download from a private repository use the
>   `--clone` flag and the cli will use `git clone` so your SSH keys are
>   used.
>
> #### Local Templates
>
> Instead of a GitHub repo, you can also use a template on your local
>   file system:
>
> ```
> vue init ~/fs/path/to-custom-template my-project
> ```

## Step by step example:

- Fork https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

  - Example: https://github.com/acdcjunior/webpack-vue-template (besides forking I have renamed the repo as well)
- IMPORTANT: Make sure you are at **`master` branch** and commit.

  - For example, to change the project description, [edit the `meta.js` file.](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/1.3.1/meta.js#L47)
  - Example of [**commit here**.](https://github.com/acdcjunior/webpack-vue-template/commit/bdf8d9b4f9e15eb068d7b89d3c700b214382eea5)
- Now use `vue init`

  - Example:

    ```
    vue init acdcjunior/webpack-vue-template my-project-from-my-template
    ```

This is valid for [Vue-cli v2.x](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/v2.9.3).